# How do i access nested array values in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, mongodb

I want to access the objects present in the array inside the another array, its like below.

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("574d2aa42ec356541dc7034e"),
"contributedProductName": "ITOS365 Radha Krishna Brass Statue Hindu God Sculpture Religious Gifts Item, 5.5 Inches",
"contributedProductId": "57459ef82b01e7802ca9294b",
"receiverId": "570dec75cf30bf4c09679deb",
"contributorDetails": [
   {
     "name": "Hemanth",
     "email": "hemanth@gmail.com",
     "amount": "500" 
   },
   {
     "name": "Kevin",
     "email": "kevinguru888@gmail.com",
     "amount": "300" 
   },
   {
     "name": "vinay",
     "email": "vinay@gmail.com",
     "amount": "149" 
   } 
 ] 
}
```

Now I want to access individual objects present in the contributorDetails array but i am getting only last object in that array. I have tried like below in angular.js controller.

### controllerFile.js

```
function ManageContributorController($http, $location, $rootScope, $localStorage)
{
    var vm = this;
    vm.uid = $localStorage._id;
    //console.log(vm.uid);
        
    $http({
            url: 'http://192.168.2.8:7200/api/manage-contributor',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {userId:vm.uid}
        }).success(function(res) {
            
            for(var key in res.result){
                for(var anotherKey in res.result[key].contributorDetails){
                    var cName = res.result[key].contributorDetails[anotherKey].name;
                    var cEmail = res.result[key].contributorDetails[anotherKey].email;
                    var cAmnt = res.result[key].contributorDetails[anotherKey].amount;
                }
                res.result[key]['contributorName']=cName;
                res.result[key]['contributorEmail']=cEmail;
                res.result[key]['contributedAmount']=cAmnt;
                
            }
            vm.result = res.result; 
            console.log(vm.result);
            
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('here');
        });     
}
```

Someone please help.
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

contributorDetails is an array within your object elements.  Try something like this

```
obj.contributorDetails[i].name, //i is the index if you know the index you want to access

//or get them all
for (var i = 0 ; i < obj.contributorDetails.length; i++)
{
  obj.contributorDetails[i].name
  obj.contributorDetails[i].email
  obj.contributorDetails[i].amount
} //in your case, obj = res.result;
```

Comment: yes, i am getting 3 object elements within for loop but outside of for loop i am getting only one that is last one.

Comment: How do i get 3 elements outside the for loop?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Based on your code, when you do (for key in res.results).  You are looping thru the elements which is _id, contributedProductName, contributedProductId..., try your loop with for each item in res.results.contributorDetails

Comment: form outside, you have to know the index... obj which is res.result based on your code, obj[index].name, email or amount.

Answer (score 0):

`contributorDetails` is a json array

You can access it like this way

```
res.contributorDetails.forEach(function(item){
 document.write('<pre>'+item.name + ' -- '+ item.email+'</pre>'+'</br>')

})
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/9sgm6rty/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
vm.result = [];
function(res) {

        for(var key in res.result){
            for(var anotherKey in res.result[key].contributorDetails){
                var cName = res.result[key].contributorDetails[anotherKey].name;
                var cEmail = res.result[key].contributorDetails[anotherKey].email;
                var cAmnt = res.result[key].contributorDetails[anotherKey].amount;
            }
            res.result[key]['contributorName']=cName;
            res.result[key]['contributorEmail']=cEmail;
            res.result[key]['contributedAmount']=cAmnt;

            vm.result.push(res.result[key); //Push into the array
        }

        console.log(vm.result);
    }
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try angular.forEach (assuming your object name to be $scope.obj):

```
angular.forEach($scope.obj.contributorDetails, function(item){

    //each item is an individual object, to access individual values you can do this:
    //item.name
    //item.email
    //item.amount

});
```